# Error involving invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' with stacks

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that is supposed to convert an infix to a post fix. During the conversion process this code keeps giving me errors regardless of how I attempt to arrange it.

```
if(addto== ')')
{
  while(opstack.top() != '('){
  stpull=opstack.top();
  pfix.append(stpull);
  }
}
```

Previously I had the opstack.top() inside of the pfix.append(), however this gave me the same error.

The error it gives me is:
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: we don't know about your `top()` and `append()` function ... please include there code also..

Comment: Top and append are default functions to the standard template library stack and string.

Comment: You are looking for `pfix.push_back(stpull);` Note though that you have an infinite loop - you keep looking at the same top element and adding it to the string over and over, never popping off the stack.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, I found that using the += operator allowed me to append the character that I wanted without issue. I have also stopped using stpull and instead just use opstack.top() now